# Why does Carthage need a Run script?

Tags: xcode, carthage, run-script

I've found countless threads on how to add the Carthage Run script, but I would like to know why is this script needed?

When adding other .frameworks to `Embedded Binaries` or `Linked Frameworks`, there's no extra step that's needed that I'm aware of. So why are frameworks build by Carthage different?

Looking at the documentation, it talks about `debug information being copied into the built products directory`. So is this Run script needed to allow desymbolication of crash logs or it's for something else?

Answer (score 0):

Run scripts works around an App Store submission bug triggered by universal binaries and ensures that necessary bitcode-related files and dSYMs are copied when archiving.